# large single join queries vs multiple smaller ones

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, scalability

So we are building this app, where the retrieval of data is based on small, modular queries. So for a product it would be something like:

```
$product = $this->product->getProductData($prod_id); //get main product record
$locations = $this->locations->getAvailableLocations($prod_id); //sale locations
$comments = $this->feedback->getFeedback($prod_id,'COMMENTS'); //user comments
```

On the other hand we could also do something like: `$this->getAllProductData($id)`
which would essentially have an `SQL` that:

```
get * from product_data 
left join locations on <...> 
left join comments on <...>
```

From a `programming` perspective, the first option makes it much easier for us to handle data, mix and match build separate flows/user experience etc. Our concern is - from a `performance` perspective would this become an issue when the products run in hundreds of thousands of rows?

Comment: If you filter by a product_id and you have indexes on it on every table I think running 3 separated querys would be worst than just one. But you should compare the execution plan on all cases and see for yourself. Put some test data on these tables and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's overhead associated with each execution of a SQL statement. Packets sent to the server, SQL text parsed, statement verified to syntactically correct (keywords, commas, parens, etc.), statement verified to be semantically correct (identifiers reference tables, columns, function, et al. exist and user has sufficient privilegs, evaluating possible execution plans and choosing optimum plan, executing the plan (obtaining locks, accessing data in buffers, etc.), materializing the resultset (metadata and values), and returning to caller, releasing locks, cleanup of resources, etc..  On the client side, there's the overhead of retrieving the resultset, fetching rows, and closing the statement.

In general, it's more efficient to retrieve the actual data that is needed with fewer statements, but not if that entials returning a whole slew of information that's not needed.  If we only need 20 rows, then we add `LIMIT 20` on the query. If we only need rows for a particular product_id, `WHERE product_id = 42`.

When we see tight loops of repeated execution of essentially the same statement, that's a tell tale sign that the developer is processing data RBER (row by excruciating row), rather than as a set.

Bottom line, it depends on the use case. Sometimes, it's more efficient to run a couple of smaller statements in place of one humongous statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use your second example (all joins in one query). As long as you have an index on "prod_id" and anything else you're filtering on or joining on, the database query optimizer will do smart things, such as seeing that prod_id will only return a few records and that doing that first will make the query about as fast as it could possibly be. Query Optimizers are *very, very good* at this in general.

Answer (score 0):

For simple joins you are probably good with one sql statement, but from my experience, multiple separate queries are better for performance when more tables are involved.

I have worked on a website where the product information was scattered across seven different tables and usually there were only two or three tables that needed to be joined. However on one page we had a complicated search function that needed to look at all seven of them, so on that page we wrote the code to join all the tables in one statement. It worked fine until a few months later, it gradually got slower and slower until it just wouldn't load altogether.

We went through all the tables and made sure everything was indexed properly and nothing was fixing it. We noticed that the sql statements were all running fine by themselves, so we ended up splitting it up into separate statements and that fixed it, haven't had to go back and look at it again.